# Incorrect syntax near '​'

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, dapper

First I was getting this error:

> Invalid object name "product_images​_temporary"

and after I have added the `[]` brackets, everything worked fine. But then when I removed them again, I got this error:

> Incorrect syntax near '​'

Why does this work:

```
[product_images​_temporary]
```

but this throws an exception ("Incorrect syntax near '​'"):

```
product_images​_temporary
```

More code:

```
try
{
    using (var sqlConnection = new DapperHelper().DatabaseConnection())
    {
        var sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM product_images​_temporary";

        sqlConnection.Execute(sqlStatement);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
}
```

Is `product_images​_temporary` a reserved word in SQL Server? Like `datetime` etc.? I can't explain this.

Comment: retype the name to eliminate the possibility of zero-width unicode tomfoolery.

Comment: @AlexK. You want me to re-type this: `"SELECT * FROM product_images​_temporary"` or something else?

Comment: Just the table name. There is a unicode character in the name that breaks it.  cast it as-is to varbinary to see exactly what.

Comment: Note that if it works with [] you should also rename the table by retyping.

Comment: Yes, there's an *invisible* unicode character between the `s` and the `_`. If you do `SELECT CONVERT(varchar(100),N'product_images​_temporary')`, you'll notice the return value is `product_images?_temporary`.

Comment: Just use an editor and use the arrow-key to step through the name. After `images`, right before the `_` you will notice, that your cursor won't move... Alex K. is right, that this - uhm - problem seems to be within the real table's name too. This is - quite probably - not what you want...

Comment: @AlexK. I have retyped it with my keyboard. :D But now I get this error: `Invalid object name 'product_images_temporary'.`.

Comment: Did you rename the table as well?

Comment: Yes, because there isn't an object called `product_images_temporary`, it's called `product_images​_temporary`. They might *look* the same, however, the first doesn't have the unicode character between the `s` and the `_`. I strongly recommend fixing your object's name.

Comment: Thanks @all! You were right... The table name in MSSQL had an "invisible character" in it. Fixed.

Comment: Write an answer so that I can upvote/accept it as the answer? :)

Comment: @AlexK. yes I have renamed the table. Now it works. The "nasty" character was in the mssql and not in the C# code. :)

Comment: @Shnugo great way to figure this things out... The arrow keys I mean. :)

Comment: @tadej well - uhm - thx :-D

Comment: So why did it work with the brackets []? Do the brackets remove these "hidden" characters?

Comment: @Tadej No, but the brackets allow for - normally illegal - names. As your table's name included this invisible character too, it was perfectly okay.  Probably some *copy'n'paste* issue.

Comment: @Shnugo thank you and yes it probably was an copy'n'paste issue. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between the `s` and the `_` is the Unicode zero-width-space character `\u200B`. This is invisible so makes the string not what it appears to be.

This character is not legal in an SQL object identifier name and is the cause of the error you see, using `[]` escapes make it legal.

Simply retype the name manually or double-delete between the two characters.

As your code does work with `[]` it means the actual table name contains `\u200B` so should also be renamed.

Answer (score 1):

Just rename the table, you have an invisible character in your table's name